# How to sort database according to Order by clause Using ASC and DESC simultaneously

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

How to sort database according to Order By clause Using ASC and DESC simultaneously?

Using this query:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY date, time, ASC, priority, DESC";
```

Comment: Can you please describe the question a little more?

Comment: you are trying to sort ASC by date and dime and sort DESC by priority?

Comment: see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY date ASC, time ASC, priority DESC";
```

Haven't tested it, but could work anyway.

Comment: This is the correct answer. +1 because I was going to give the very same response.

Comment: and +1 because we welcome new users.

Answer (score 1):

You should dive more into SQL query building before programming such applications.

SQLite's ORDER BY reference manual [here](https://sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby). MySQL's ORDER BY reference manual [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html).

Pasted from MySQL's manual:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
ORDER BY key_part1 DESC, key_part2 DESC;
```

Now, you should be able to find where problem is.

Answer (score 0):

you may want this:

```
SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY date ASC, time DESC;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY date, time ASC, priority DESC;
```

you can view the structure of the whole Select statement [here](https://sqlite.org/images/syntax/select-stmt.gif)

[image]

and the **ordering-term**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL Query.

```
SELECT * FROM contacts ORDER BY time ASC, priority DESC;
```

Here it is order by Time in Ascending order and then by priority in descending order.